# Submit button load same page with button disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, button

My code loads the same page after clicking the button, but I want the page loaded with the button disabled. Below is the java script code.

```
function disableSendVerifButton()
{
   $( '.sendVerificationButton' ).html( 'Verification Sent' );
   $( '.sendVerificationButton' ).attr( "disabled", true );

   // Change the button color
   $( '.sendVerificationButton' ).addClass( 'gray' );
}
```

But since the same page loads, the button does not gets disabled and loads with normal button. Please help.

Comment: You need to store the state of the button somehow. If you're using HTML5, you could use localStorage, otherwise, you could also store the state in the $_SESSION. Reason: On a page reload, the whole JS is reinitialisated

Comment: Assuming your page is the same both times, you would need to change something on the page - either from a backend script, or perhaps in the query string (which you can use in the js), or a cookie.  Do you need to do this purely in javascript?

Comment: @moo2u2: No it is not hard and fast rule to use java script only. Suggestions are welcome to use other methods as well. One more thing is that once I go away from that page and come back again the button should be enabled again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a query string on the page on reload/submit, f.ex:

```
http://domain.com/?submitted
```

Then look for it in javascript:

```
if ( /^\?submitted/.test(window.location.search) ) {
    disableSendVerifButton();
}
```

**Using a cookie**: do somehting like this on submit/click *before* reload:

```
document.cookie='submitted=1;'
```

And then:

```
if ( /submitted\=1;/.test(document.cookie) ) {
    document.cookie='submitted=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;'
    disableSendVerifButton();
}
```

Other options are localstorage or submitting through ajax.

Comment: What is the option of cookie ? Could you pls explain.

Comment: @arpit_s added a simple cookie example. But I would go for query string.